Transaction input args deserialization
How can I deserialize the input args on Solana if I know the data structure and the "Instruction Data Raw"?
Example transaction:
https://solscan.io/tx/5Xk8HMqYuNsVkJwh15pgTVtjF8eKDfriJC39pR4NxNCjxNeMZ4ZXC3YqH9mcvfKF9JtCyNJhJn5JTe6X9PsmXaYu
